# escaping special characters in sql for generating xml file

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, escaping

I am using SQL server 2008 and I'm quite new to writing sql. My aim is to export data from a table into xml format to create a CAP xml file that can be used in our website. Currently, I'm just writing some select statements to retrieve data in the correct format. Here is the code:

```
select (SELECT TOP 5 [Master_Incident_Number] AS incidents
,[Jurisdiction] AS jurisdiction
,[Response_Date] AS Date
FROM [ESCAD_DW_System].[dbo].[CurrentIncidents_V] Incident 
FOR XML PATH ('area'), type ) AS Alert for xml path (''), 
ROOT ('?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?')
```

However, I am getting 'invalid XML identifier' error for '?' symbol. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `ROOT` to add an xml encoding tag. The only way to do that is to convert the xml output into `varchar(max)` and prepend with your encoding tag. Keep in mind though that `FOR XML` output is UTF-16 by default, and therefore your UTF-8 encoding is probably unnecessary. Having said that, here is a simple example that uses a UDF to convert the xml into `varchar(max)`:

```
create function gimmexml()
returns varchar(max)
as
begin
    return (
        select a='some', b='xml'
        for xml path ('')           
    )
end
go

select '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'+dbo.gimmexml();
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><a>some</a><b>xml</b>
```

Further reading:
http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.sqlserver.xml/topic60022.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345137%28v=sql.90%29.aspx